# Nodemcu: UDP communication gets influenced if there is/isn't udp listener?

Tags: networking, lua, udp, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a weird problem with nodemcu firmware (2.1.0) on an ESP8266, where I'm running out of ideas what else I could try to solve the issue.

I have a simple lua script running, which is listening on UDP for commands to switch a relay on and off, and sending alive messages via UDP every 60 seconds to a defined IP address.

If there is nothing listening on the server side which is supposed to get the UDP "alive" messages, ESP reacts fine, all good. 
As soon as I start netcat to listen to the UDP packages coming from ESP, the ESP will start to hang every couple of minutes for at least 30-60 seconds. 
It is specifically confusing as I'm expecting UDP to be a connectionless protocol. So how can a listener on UDP influence the behavior of the sender?
These are the relevant parts of the lua script:

```
[...]
alive=60000
[...]

function srvupd(s)
if (connected==1) then
  s = s .." "..ip
  srv:send(serverport, serveradr, s.."\n")
  end;
end;

if (alive>0) then
tmr.alarm(2, alive, 1, function()
    srvupd("alive")
    end)
end

srv=net.createUDPSocket() 
srv:listen(80)
srv:on("sent", function()
    srv:close();
    srv:listen(80);
    end)
srv:on("receive",function(client,request, port, ip)
    if (alive>0) then tmr.stop(2) end
    print(string.format("received '%s' from %s:%d", request, ip, port))
    buf="unknown"

    if (request == "ch1on") then gpio.write(relay1, relayon);buf="ok" end

[...]

    client:send(port, ip, buf)
    if (alive>0) then tmr.start(2) end
end)
```

And this is how I use netcat to listen to the UDP messages from ESP in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
msg=$(netcat -4 -u -n -l -D 192.168.0.5 2701 -w0 -q0)
echo -e "$msg"
done
```

In the situation where ESP is not reacting to UDP commands anymore, the alive messages are still sending every minute. The UDP commands are even received by the ESP, because as soon as processing continues, a "channel-on" command sent some time ago gets executed.

These temporary blockings of ESP only happens when I listen to its UDP messages. 
I've checked all kind of combinations, like separate UDP-sockets for the listener and the alive sending on the ESP, closing and opening the server, after message was sent (like in the current version above) etc.
I've even tried to receive commands via TCP and only send the alive messages via UDP. 
Behaviour remains the same. All works, as long as there is nothing receiving the UDP messages from ESP. As soon as I start netcat, ESP startes to hang within a couple of minutes.

Any ideas? As it is UDP it is already difficult to understand how it can happen at all.

kind regards
Tjareson

Comment: Have you tried a different tool like Wireshark to see if it is just your bash script and not the ESP causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved meanwhile. A friend of mine was pointing me to the only common basis for the UDP issue, which is ARP.

The behaviour only occured, when ESP was in a different network than the udp-listener. (like 192.168.1.x and 192.168.5.y)
Even if it remains a bit unclear, the guessing is that probably netcat is making an ARP request when receiving a message and that this somehow isn't properly processed by the router, if taking place between two different networks.

After putting the listener bashscript in the same network (basically by giving the raspberry on which it runs a second IP in the network the ESP is in), the blocked ESP communication didn't happen again.